# Please help and advice with hover underline menu items

Tags: css, wordpress, hover, edit, underline

thank you in advance for your help. I need advice and help on how to edit: wp menu items underline.

I used this css code to implement the underlining:

```
a:hover {
color: black;
text-decoration: underline;
```

}

My site: https://www.webpreludi.online

My question is how please can I edit the underline, I would like to change the line thickness and separate it by a few pixels from the text below.

Thanks so much , realy im novice, and make page for my wife, please make my answer thanks sou mych.

Answer (score 0):

Use a border instead. Then you can move it closer or further with padding.

```
a:hover {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: waw you are super please would you help me how to learn to better understand css editing. as you learned it. thank you very much. and it is possible add line under text but only bold?

Comment: I would like you to guide me and help me how to start editing css wo wordpress. ? where do i start how did you learn it?

Comment: I started learning html back in 1999. Been doing it a few years now 

Comment: Basically, just keep on doing what you’re doing now. Keep trying new things and keep learning. CSS Tricks is a great website as well as w3schools. Code Academy is great as well.

Comment: Dan Mullin - it is possible make for me this. when you have time and i give you micro 20€ pay out for this- it is possible.I would like to change the dots - below the gallery. dots tear like a slider. and I would like to change it to a line where the thick line will be like a slider. It is possible? And if so as please. Thank you for advice. I am also willing to send a cash micro reward of 20 € for a working change. I need to change this in several galleries. I send on your e mails screen shot what i need. 
thank you if yes and if no no

Comment: Please i make your code and when i make hover efekt my menu jumping . My page it is https://www.webpreludi.online/ . it is possible hepl my.